# Overlay several artists in legend entry

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add an entry to a legend that has a patch in the background. The desired effect is similar to what is shown [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists), but I'd also like to overlay a line. Basicaly I'm trying to get something that looks like this:

[image]

But I don't know how to put the blue dotted line on the yellow patch. How would one go about combining artists to get this effect? I don't see any examples or obvious ways to do it.

Comment: Could you draw a little diagram? Something scrawled in MSPaint would be enough for context.

Comment: @Veedrac hopefully that clears stuff up a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea is to use `plt.legend([(X, Y)])` to render `X` and `Y` in the same legend entry. Note the extra pair of parentheses.

Here's a demo approximately matching your example:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

yellow_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='yellow')
blue_dotted_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], linewidth=2, linestyle="--", dashes=(3.7, 2), color='blue')
brown_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], linewidth=2, color='brown')

plt.legend([(yellow_patch, blue_dotted_line), brown_line], ["Entry One", "Entry Two"])

plt.show()
```

[image: The legend approximately matching the wanted image.]

You're right though, it's not obvious.

Comment: wow, that's incredibly easy. I admit, the idea crossed my mind, but I thought "no way that will _just work_"...

Comment: Also interesting that it works with `(red_patch, blue_dotted_line)` but not with `[red_patch, blue_dotted_line]`